# Deleted part of code is still being executed in web browser

Tags: html, css

I **deleted** footer code from the HTML file. However, when I run the HTML file, I still see the footer being displayed in the browser.
Could this be because I did not clear the web browser cache?

Please find below the HTML file and screenshot of web browser:

**HTML file**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Charles Darwin - biography</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Darwin.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Charles Darwin</h1>
            <h3>(biography)</h3>
        </header>
        <section class="container">
            <section class="jumbotron">
                <div class="row">
                <figure class="col-sm-5 сol-sm-7">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="image/Charles-Darwin.jpg" alt="CharlesDarwin" />
                    <figcaption>Biologist, Scientist (1809–1882)</figcaption>
                    <p class="desc">
                        <span class="dec3"> QUICK FACTS </span> <br><br>
                        <span class="dec"> FULL NAME </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec2">Charles Robert Darwin </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec"> BIRTH DATE </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec2">February 12, 1809 </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec"> DEATH DATE </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec2">April 19, 1882 </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec"> PLACE OF BIRTH </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec2">Shrewsbury, England </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec"> PLACE OF DEATH </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec2">Downe, England </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec"> EDUCATION </span> <br>
                        <span class="dec2">University of Edinburgh, Cambridge </span> </p>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                        <p><b>Synopsis</b></p>
                            <p>Naturalist Charles Darwin was born in Shrewsbury, England, on February 12, 1809. In 1831, he embarked on a five-year survey voyage around the world on the HMS Beagle. His studies of specimens around the globe led him to formulate his theory of evolution and his views on the process of natural selection. In 1859, he published On the Origin of Species. He died on April 19, 1882, in London.</p>
                                <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse"><i>“A man who dares to waste one hour of time has not discovered the value of life.”
                                <br>-Charles Darwin</i></blockquote>
                        <p><b>Early Life</b></p>
                            <p>Naturalist Charles Robert Darwin was born on February 12, 1809, in the tiny merchant town of Shrewsbury, England. He was the second youngest of six children. Darwin came from a long line of scientists. His father, Dr. R.W. Darwin, was as a medical doctor, and his grandfather, Dr. Erasmus Darwin, was a renowned botanist. Darwin’s mother, Susanna, died when he was only 8 years old. Darwin was a child of wealth and privilege who loved to explore nature.In October 1825, at age 16, Darwin enrolled at Edinburgh University along with his brother Erasmus. Two years later, Charles Darwin became a student at Christ's College in Cambridge. His father hoped he would follow in his footsteps and become a medical doctor, but the sight of blood made Darwin queasy. His father suggested he study to become a parson instead, but Darwin was far more inclined to study natural history.</p> <br>
                        <p><b>Voyage on the HMS Beagle</b></p>
                            <p>While Darwin was at Christ's College, botany professor John Stevens Henslow became his mentor. After Darwin graduated Christ's College with a bachelor of arts degree in 1831, Henslow recommended him for a naturalist’s position aboard the HMS Beagle. The ship, commanded by Captain Robert FitzRoy, was to take a five-year survey trip around the world. The voyage would prove the opportunity of a lifetime for the budding young naturalist.
                            <br>
                            On December 27, 1831, the HMS Beagle launched its voyage around the world with Darwin in tow. Over the course of the trip, Darwin collected a variety of natural specimens, including birds, plants and fossils. Through hands-on research and experimentation, he had the unique opportunity to closely observe principles of botany, geology and zoology. The Pacific Islands and Galapagos Archipelago were of particular interest to Darwin, as was South America.
                            <br>
                            Upon his return to England in 1836, Darwin began to write up his findings in the Journal of Researches, published as part of Captain FitzRoy's larger narrative and later edited into the Zoology of the Voyage of the Beagle. The trip had a monumental affect on Darwin’s view of natural history. He began to develop a revolutionary theory about the origin of living beings that was contrary to the popular view of other naturalists at the time.</p>
                            <p><b>Theory of Evolution</b></p>
                            <p>Darwin's exposure to specimens all over the globe raised important questions. Other naturalists believed that all species either came into being at the start of the world, or were created over the course of natural history. In either case, the species were believed to remain much the same throughout time. Darwin, however, noticed similarities among species all over the globe, along with variations based on specific locations, leading him to believe that they had gradually evolved from common ancestors. He came to believe that species survived through a process called "natural selection," where species that successfully adapted to meet the changing requirements of their natural habitat thrived, while those that failed to evolve and reproduce died off.</p>
                            <br>
                            <p>In 1858, after years of further scientific investigation, Darwin publically introduced his revolutionary theory of evolution in a letter read at a meeting of the Linnean Society. On November 24, 1859, he published a detailed explanation of his theory in his best-known work, <i> On the Origin of Species by Means of Natural Selection.</i></p>
                            <p><b>Death and Legacy</b></p>
                            <p>Following a lifetime of devout research, Charles Darwin died at his family home, Down House, in London, on April 19, 1882, and was buried at Westminster Abbey. During the next century, DNA studies revealed evidence of his theory of evolution, although controversy surrounding its conflict with Creationism—the religious view that all of nature was born of God—still abounds today.</p>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="row">
                        <figure class="col-sm-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-3 ">
                            </figure>

                        <figure class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A0VnuhHq5m0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                        </figure>

                    </div>
            </section>
        </section>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Screenshot of the HTML file as rendered in the web browser**

[image]

Comment: have  you  save the file ? are you  opening that file(modified) ?

Comment: hold ctrl+shift+r to clear your browser's cache. cmd_shift+r for mac.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/diciseviho/edit?html,output  this  is working

Comment: yea  clear cache how  @PootieTang says

Comment: It's impossible to debug your code with this information ... I will bet that you are refreshing the wrong html file.

Comment: Is the footer automatically created by a library?

Comment: Pootie Tang - Thank you, it helped =)